# What's the best way to compose multiple Docker images with different bases

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I would like to compose multiple Docker images that start with different bases. However, many of the installation scripts afterward are similar.

What's the best way to `source` a sub Docker file?

Comment: Compose is probably not the best word for this given there's already a tool called *docker-compose*. What are the images, what do they have in common? Do they belong to the same project?

Comment: Let's say that I want to have something similar to this (https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/blob/master/scipy-notebook/Dockerfile) but with a different starting point, such as this (https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/blob/master/ubuntu-16.04/cuda/8.0/devel/Dockerfile) instead of ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like what you're looking for is the ability to include Dockerfiles in other Dockerfiles. There was a [proposal](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/735) for such a feature, but currently there is nothing that supports this out of the box. The discussion is worth reading through because it includes links to tools like [harbor](https://github.com/leethomas/harbor) and [dfpp](https://github.com/coryb/dfpp) that people built to a support a subset of the functionality.

One problem with tools like this is that you can't easily make the same include file work for debian, centos, and alpine linux (for example). The way this is currently addressed (like [redis](https://github.com/docker-library/redis/blob/master/3.2/Dockerfile) and [redis-alpine](https://github.com/docker-library/redis/blob/master/3.2/alpine/Dockerfile) images for essentially the same software) is to have duplicate dockerfiles.